# Regex - find matches that are like [Attribute:GUID]

Tags: c#, regex

I have a large string of html, with several tokens that follow the format:

```
[Attribute:GUID]
```

so for example, there are many tokens like this: `[Attribute:5c1670bb-b6ac-4fb5-92ab-9e0ea4bf72e8]`

How can I get all matches for that? I started by just using `[Attribute:d+]`, but apparently the `[` symbol is a regex token that I can't use, but I need to search for it

Comment: Could you post more data ?

Comment: It is as easy as [`\[Attribute:([^][]+)]`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5bAttribute%3a(%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d%2b)%5d&i=%5bAttribute%3a5c1670bb-b6ac-4fb5-92ab-9e0ea4bf72e9%5d+%5bAttribute%3a5c1670bb-b6ac-4fb5-92ab-9e0ea4bf72e8%5d+%5bAttribute%3a5c1670bb-b6ac-4fb5-92ab-9e0ea4bf72e7%5d)

Answer (score 1):

> I have a large string of html, with several tokens that follow the
>   format:
>
> ```
> [Attribute:GUID]
> ```
>
> so for example, there are many tokens like this:
>   `[Attribute:5c1670bb-b6ac-4fb5-92ab-9e0ea4bf72e8]`
>
> How can I get all matches for that? I started by just using
>   `[SiteAttribute:d+]`, but apparently the `[` symbol is a regex token
>   that I can't use, but I need to search for it

If you need to search for a literal "[" use the escaped value "\[" in your regex.

For example (similar to your "SiteAttribute" example):

```
"\[SiteAttribute:\d.*\]"
```

Or:

```
"\[Attribute:\d.*\]"
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to escape `[` and `]` like this.

**Regex:** `\[Attribute:[a-z0-9-]+\]`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jF7fX0/1)**

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what can be your attribute. If it can be any "word" consisted of alphabetical characters, it's:

```
\[[A-Za-z]+:[a-z0-9\-]+\]
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that each `GUID` pattern is not valid, so pattern checking should be considered.

Following method can act in two modes, calling with forced to checking `GUID` validity in the pattern and calling without checking `GUID` pattern validity.

```
private List<string> GetListOfValidAttributeGuids(string strInput, bool blGuidValidityCheck = true)
{
    string strRegExAttrGuid = new Regex(@"\[Attribute:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\]").ToString();
    MatchCollection lstMatchedAttrGuid = Regex.Matches(strInput, strRegExAttrGuid);
    List<string> lstMatchedAttrGuidValue = lstMatchedAttrGuid.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();

    if(blGuidValidityCheck)
    {
        string strRegExGuid = new Regex(@":[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+").ToString();
        List<string> lstValidMatchedAttrGuid = new List<string>();

        foreach (string lst in lstMatchedAttrGuidValue)
        {
            MatchCollection validMatchedAttrGuid = Regex.Matches(lst, strRegExGuid);
            string validMatchedAttrGuidValue = validMatchedAttrGuid.Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value).Single().Substring(1);

            Guid guidTemp;
            bool isValidGuid = Guid.TryParse(validMatchedAttrGuidValue, out guidTemp);

            if (isValidGuid)
                lstValidMatchedAttrGuid.Add(lst);
        }

        return lstValidMatchedAttrGuid;
    }

    return lstMatchedAttrGuidValue;
}
```

For example look at two following method calls:

```
string strInput = "In yek attribute mo'tabar hast: [Attribute:5c1670bb-b6ac-4fb5-92ab-9e0ea4bf72e8] " +
                    " va in yeki mo'tabar nist: [Attribute:7A7CE329-1338-4505-88B1-EA6B28BDE264E]";

List<string> call_01 = GetListOfValidAttributeGuids(strInput, false);
List<string> call_02 = GetListOfValidAttributeGuids(strInput, true);
```

Here `call_01` has *two* elements stored in it but `call_02` has *one* element.

Comment: **(\{){0,1}[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}(\}**  also can be used for checking GUID format.